# How to to keep this merge array method in-bounds?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, merge, indexoutofboundsexception

I have to write a method that combines two arrays that are already in ascending order into one array sorted in ascending order. However, they are different lengths and so incrementing brings them out of bounds.

[Visualization](http://cscircles.cemc.uwaterloo.ca/java_visualize/#code=public+class+ClassNameHere+%7B%0A+++public+static+void+main(String%5B%5D+args)+%7B%0A++++++int%5B%5D+nums1+%3D+%7B2,5,8%7D%3B%0A++++++int%5B%5D+nums2+%3D+%7B4,7,9%7D%3B%0A++++++int%5B%5D+arr+%3D+new+int%5Bnums1.length%2Bnums2.length%5D%3B%0A++%0A++int+index_1%3D0%3B%0A++int+index_2%3D0%3B%0A++int+content_1%3D0%3B%0A++int+content_2%3D0%3B%0A++for(int+steps%3D0%3Bsteps%3Carr.length%26%26index_1%3Cnums1.length%26%26index_2%3Cnums2.length%3Bsteps%2B%2B)+%7B%0A++++content_1%3Dnums1%5Bindex_1%5D%3B%0A++++content_2%3Dnums2%5Bindex_2%5D%3B%0A++++%0A++++if(content_1%3Ccontent_2)+%7B%0A++++%0A++++++arr%5Bsteps%5D%3Dcontent_1%3B%0A++++++index_1%2B%2B%3B%0A++++++%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++if(content_1%3Econtent_2)+%7B%0A++++%0A++++++arr%5Bsteps%5D%3Dcontent_2%3B%0A++++++index_2%2B%2B%3B%0A++++++%0A++++%7D%0A++%0A++%7D%0A++++%0A+++%7D%0A%7D&mode=display&curInstr=51)

```
int[] mergeTwo(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
      int[] arr = new int[nums1.length+nums2.length];

  int index_1=0;
  int index_2=0;
  int content_1=0;
  int content_2=0;
  for(int steps=0;steps<arr.length&&index_1<nums1.length&&index_2<nums2.length;steps++) {
    content_1=nums1[index_1];
    content_2=nums2[index_2];

    if(content_1<content_2) {

      arr[steps]=content_1;
      index_1++;

    }

    if(content_1>content_2) {

      arr[steps]=content_2;
      index_2++;

    }

  }

  return arr;  
}
```

What do I need to fix to make this method work? Thanks so much!

Comment: Where are you getting `outofbounds` exception?

Comment: After you break out of loop add the remaining elements(from one of the arrays) to the final array

Comment: On the last iteration, because the arrays can be different lengths, it would throw the exception. The issue is if I don't have `steps<arr.length&&index_1<nums1.length&&index_2<nums2.length` then it will go out of bounds, but doing it this way won't finish because one of these conditions being false will end the loop. If you take a look at the last few steps of the visualization, you'll see what's going on with it.

Comment: Only if you `don't have that condition` you get exception. So you must clearly tell what your problem is in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you break out of loop add the remaining elements(from one of the arrays) to the final array

```
while(index_1  < nums1.length)
{

    arr[steps] = nums1[index_1];
    index_1++;
    steps++;
}
while(index_2  < nums2.length)
{
    arr[steps] = nums2[index_2];
    index_2++;
    steps++;
}
```